# "Server cannot accept argument" exception thrown by FTP server in IIS in Azure VM

Tags: c#, azure, iis, ftp, azure-virtual-machine

Following the code i'am using to connect to the FTP server.

```
client.Mode = FtpMode.Active;
client.ActiveModePorts = new Range(10000, 10001);
client.Connect(ftpModel.ftpServer, ftpModel.ftpPort);
client.Login(ftpModel.ftpUser, ftpModel.ftpPassword);
```

I'am using Ftp.dll nuget packaage for development.

1. The error Thrown by Visual Studio

[image: The error Thrown by Visual Studio]

2. FTP Firewall support

[image: FTP Firewall support]

3. Firewall Inbound Rules

[image: Firewall Inbound Rules]

4. Inbound rules of Azure VM

[image: Inbound rules of Azure VM]

5. Inbound rule in my local Machine

[image: Inbound rule in my local Machine]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure VM, we can't use FTP in active mode, please try to use **passive mode**.

In active mode FTP the client connects from a random unprivileged port (N > 1023) to the FTP server's command port, port 21. Then, the client starts listening to port N+1 and sends the FTP command PORT N+1 to the FTP server. The server will then connect back to the client's specified data port from its local data port, which is port 20.
Here is the connection appears as follows:
[image]